# Drupal 7 CDN Module not altering URLs for themed Pages

Tags: 7, cdn

I have themed a page on my Drupal 7 website by mentioning the template file as 
page--node--.tpl.php 
The CSS and Images which are coming on this page are getting picked from the site itself and not from the static url i have configured in CDN.
Other than this page my website is picking CSS JS & Images from CDN
Any suggestions ?

Basic page--node--123.tpl.php

```
<?php
global $base_url;
$img_actl_path =  "$base_url/".drupal_get_path('theme','theme-name')."/images/v1/";
?>
<a href="#"><img src="<?php print $img_actl_path;?>image1.jpg" width="380" height="197" /></a>
```

Comment: I created a new template with just image in anchor tag ( code updated in question ). Even this is not picking image from CDN

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not using the Drupal API.

The [CDN](https://drupal.org/project/CDN) module needs to be able to alter the path from your Drupal site to your CDN.  It does this by catching the URL via [`hook_file_url_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7), and changing it.

The proper way to to make a URL in this case is with [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7).  Something like this should work

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');
  $variables['mysrc'] = file_create_url($path . '/images/v1/image1.jpg');
}
```

And then in your theme you would use

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php print $mysrc; ?>" width="380" height="197" /></a>
```

However, as [Mołot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/molot) suggests, using a proper theme function to make a renderable image would probably be best.